# Sous vide chuck roast or chuck steaks?

Tags: beef, sous-vide

I've never cooked sous vide before, but am now equipped to try thanks to the holidays.

We have a 3 pound chuck roast -- I'm not sure what the exact cut shape is, but it's vaguely cube shaped. If we cut the roast into steaks (1-2 inches thick) before bagging and cooking, what effect would this have on the cooking time and/or quality?

Comment: I thought I'd at least answer your question... sous vide cooking is a function of temperature and the surface area to volume ratio of the food in question.  If you have a high surface area to volume the cooking time will be shorter.  Steaks would have a higher ratio than the roast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sous vide cooking is a function of temperature and the surface area to volume ratio of the food in question.

If you have a high surface area to volume the cooking time will be shorter. Steaks would have a higher ratio than the roast so they would take less time than the roast.  The amount of the time difference is difficult to predict exactly over such a long time scale, but a rough calculation of the ratio I spoke of would be a good starting point for a compensation factor.

If you have the time and your water bath can accommodate, I'd suggest keeping the roast whole and finishing in a skillet.  It's much more impressive than a steak.

Answer (score 4):

That's the first thing I did with my Anova circulator.

[image: 1]

It turns chuck into ribeye! (so to speak) Notice no grey border? And the perfect medium rare?!

I don't know about sous-vide cooking chuck as a roast (although I do have a recipe), because I haven't done it (yet). It turned out so great as a steak that I'll probably do at least one more as steaks before I do a roast. I live alone so I'd rather have 5 steaks vacuum packed in the freezer than 1 beautifully cooked roast.

That is chuck, circulated for 60 hours (no joke, although I did one for 36 hours that was almost as good) at 131F. The long time is necessary to break down all of that delicious connective tissue.

Then I seared in a NASA hot cast iron skillet.

It was so good! I sprinkled with salt and pepper just before I seared, that was all the seasoning I used. Great steak for the price of hamburger :)

Good luck! Enjoy!

Comment: That looks terrific. I need to start TONIGHT on this -- it's going to be Friday's dinner :)

Comment: @Erica Enjoy! It works great. You won't believe you're eating chuck. It really does seem like ribeye.

Comment: based on my office, 'NASA hot' requires a space heater so you don't freeze.

Comment: Is that a chuck steak, or a chuck eye? Looks like the latter, which can be cooked just like a ribeye. It's actually the continuation of the rib muscle, into the chuck roll.

Comment: @SeanHart It's just a chuck roast that I cut into 5 steaks. That one was in the middle somewhere. The roast looked like this: http://3dvalleyfarms.com/product/chuck-roast-boneless/